# Restore Shutdown / Suspend / Restart / etc. menu before logout in Xubuntu 22.04

Tags: xubuntu, suspend, power-management, xfce, 22.04

I noticed that recently, in my Xubuntu 22.04 system (recently upgraded from 21.10), I cannot put my PC in standby (aka sleep or suspend) mode, and not even turn it off, without logging out. I did not notice if it was immediatly after 22.04 upgrade, or with some more recent system upgrade, but I suspect the latter.

Anyway, where in my start menu once was a sort of "I/O" button, that brought up a window with Exit - Sleep - Power Off - Hybernate options, now appears a logout button:

[image: The button to log out, in the position once occupied by the one to show various options]

This is a photo of how the button was (taken from the internet):

[image: The button I miss so much]

And this is the photo of the logout menu that once I could bring up by pressing that button (again picture from the internet) and I can't find a way to access anymore:

[image: The menu I miss so much]

Now, instead of the menu, I get immediatly logged out, back in login screen with all my running programs closed. From that login screen, I can turn off my PC and even put it in standby, which is quite useless since my session has been previously closed.

The same happens when I try another way I used to make that menu appear, which was to click in a random point in my desktop and press Alt+F4.

By now, I'm putting my PC in standby mode by CLI with `systemctl suspend`, but I'd like to know if I can somehow restore the GUI methods. Thanks in advice to everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is controlled by 'Settings -> Session and Startup -> Prompt on logout'.

Comment: Thanks, it was that!